# How many ways to distribute these balls?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

There is a box of balls containing six different colors of balls. More precisely there are
nine, eight, five, seven, two, and four of the various colors for a total of 35 balls. If eight people
take balls from the box, in how many ways can the balls be distributed? (There are no restrictions how many balls one person can get, so one person can get all 35 and the others get nothing).

Is it correct that there are $8^{35}$ ways to distribute the balls? The balls are distinct, but there are different numbers of each color, so that's what is getting me. I think the answer might involve n choose k but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: So the balls of the same color are identical?

Comment: Are the balls distributed instantaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be $8^{35}$ if the $35$ balls were numbered or otherwise distinguishable. As it is, the $9$ balls of the first color are presumably indistinguishable, so there’s only one way for the first person to get $5$ of them and the second person $4$, not the $\binom95$ ways that there would be if the $9$ balls were numbered or otherwise made individually identifiable.

Suppose that you knew that there were $n_1$ ways to distribute the $9$ balls of the first color amongst the $8$ people, $n_2$ ways to distribute the $8$ balls of the second color, and so on. You could then calculate the number of possible distributions of all $35$ balls amongst the $8$ people; how?

Calculating each these numbers $n_1,\ldots,n_6$ is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem. And your problem as a whole is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236828/number-of-ways-to-distribute-55-red-balls-and-3-green-balls?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I now have that $n_1 = {{16}\choose{7}}$, $n_2 = {{15}\choose{7}}$, $n_3 =  {{12}\choose{7}}$, $n_4 = {{14}\choose{7}}$, $n_5 = {{9}\choose{7}}$, and $n_6 = {{11}\choose{7}}$. I believe that I applied the stars and bars approach correctly. Would I now multiply these together to solve in how many ways  the balls can be distributed?

Comment: @mathstudent288: You’re welcome. You would indeed.